# Return a default value in group by if selected column is null

Tags: postgresql, group-by, null

I am trying to run a group by statement which works fine however, one of the "group" is null.  How do I return "Unknown" for that row?

For example:

```
    10000
A   9999
B   9990
C   4
```

etc.

First line I'd like to return as "Unknown" in the query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use [`COALESCE(your_column, 'Unknown')`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL):

> The COALESCE function returns the first of its arguments that is not null.

This is not specific to `GROUP BY`, although you'll certainly need to use it both in your `SELECT` column expression and in the `GROUP BY` expression (as usual when using `GROUP BY`).

Comment: Fan-freaking-tastic

Comment: If it's that great, please mark Bruno's answer as correct.